# Unable to programmatically set form background image from picture resource

Tags: c#, winforms

I just want to set the background image of another form to a png file picture resource I added

I have the following in my MAstrategyBldrForm.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MAStrategyBuilder
{
    public partial class MAstrategyBldrForm : Form
    {

        private CrossPicsForm crossPic;

        public MAstrategyBldrForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            crossPic = new CrossPicsForm();
        }
```

....
....
.... later in same file:

```
private void MAcrossPicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    crossPic.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap) (Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Moving Avgs Cross.png"));
    crossPic.Show();
}
```

....
.... 
In my CrossPicsForm.cs file I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MAStrategyBuilder
{
    public partial class CrossPicsForm : Form
    {
        public CrossPicsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything compiles but when I click my button control in the mastrategy... form, a CrossPicsForm window is displayed that is blank. Darn!

Comment: Just a suggestion: did you try to remove whitespace in the image name ?

Comment: Try That please:        var WhatIsMyValueWhenBreakPointHit = (Bitmap) (Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Moving Avgs Cross.png"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get an exception when you mis-spell the resource name, ResourceManager simply returns null and that leaves the BackgroundImage property unchanged.  You did, it would normally be named "Moving_Avgs_Cross" without the .png extension.

Do favor using the property that was added by the resource designer instead.  That ought to resemble:

```
crossPic.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Moving_Avgs_Cross;
```

Use IntelliSense to help you fall in the pit of success here.